# How to differentiate between positive and negative numbers in search

Tags: control-panel, search

I discovered today that searching a custom field for a number will return results containing either the positive or negative versions of the number, even if I do an exact search. For example: `fieldName::"-2"` will give me entries where that field contains either "2" or "-2". Same result if I search for `fieldName::"2"`. The field in question is a "number" field.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's happening:

When Craft's [SearchService](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/SearchService) indexes the keywords for a field, they go though a [normalization](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/services/SearchService.php#L302) process that specifically removes [punctuation and diacritics](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/helpers/StringHelper.php#L365) before being saved to the `craft_searchindex` table in the database.

In the case of numeric values, that's going to include things like decimals, grouping separators and negation symbols.

A workaround if you're doing this on a front-end search form, is to query the field's value directly, bypassing the SearchService. So...

```
{% set results = craft.entries.fieldName('-2').find() %}
```

Which is going to try and do a direct match against that field's actual value in the `craft_content` table.

There are a few feature requests you might want to add your voice to that would make your situation better as well:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1630

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/833

Comment: Gotcha. Unfortunately I need this in the control panel entries list. I'll add a comment to that FR.